# View doesn't reappear after setVisibility(View.GONE)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout which I'm trying to make VISIBLE, then GONE, then VISIBLE again. However after making it GONE, it doesn't become visible again. As a note, it works fine if I make it INVISIBLE: it appears and disappears with no problem.

These are my files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/noconnectionll"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
        android:background="@color/category_no_internet"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/no_internet_short"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no_connection_retry"
            android:text="@string/try_again"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner_wrapper"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="#a0ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_loading"
            android:text="@string/loading"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the method I'm using to show/hide:

```
private void hideOrShowLoading(final boolean show) {

    final ViewGroup spinnerWrapper = (ViewGroup)ll.findViewById(R.id.spinner_wrapper);
    final View spinner = ll.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    if (show) {
        spinnerWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Not working after being set to GONE previously
        final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotate);
        rotation.setFillAfter(true);
        spinner.startAnimation(rotation);
    } else {
        spinnerWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinner.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

Any tips? Could it have something to do with the ListView above it having a height of 0 and a weight of 1?

Thanks

**Update**

I also tried the following after the `if (show)` block, with no luck:

```
    listview.invalidate();
    spinnerWrapper.invalidate();
    ll.invalidate();
    ll.requestLayout();
```

`ll` is the LinearLayout that contains both.

Comment: Seems to work OK. Is `show` being set correctly?

Comment: Have a try to remove attribute tools:visibility="visible" and android:visibility="invisible" in LinearLayout "spinner_wrapper"

Comment: make sure hideOrShowLoading() is running in UI thread.

Comment: @rdbmsa Yes, just logged a `Thread.currentThread().getName()` and it is main.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, I removed the `android:visibility="invisible"` from the layout file but it behaves the same.

Comment: @Cheticamp Yes. I tested this by just changing the background color instead of changing visibility and it works correctly that way. So the `show` param is being sent correctly.

Comment: What's in your animation? Can you post the XML here? Have you tried your code without the animation to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @Cheticamp Yep, I tried removing the animation and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

While I believe this is caused by the `layout_weight=1` property, I wasn't able to properly fix this.

The following hack did work. Basically, I'm surrounding the `spinnerWrapper` in another linear layout which is always visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/noconnectionll"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="@dimen/node_default_spacing"
        android:background="@color/category_no_internet"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/no_internet_short"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no_connection_retry"
            android:text="@string/try_again"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        tools:background="#d496d4"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <!-- Weird bug with layout_weight=1 on the listview above means we need this linearlayout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#0ca917"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/spinner_wrapper"
            android:background="#a0ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_loading"
                android:text="@string/loading"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```